# How can I remove a participant from a GitHub pull request?

Tags: github, pull-request

I've created a pull request and assigned it to one of my co-workers ("Brian") to review. He's since told me he's not available, so I've reassigned it to a different co-worker ("Geoff"). I now have a pull request with 3 listed participants: myself, Brian and Geoff.

How can I remove the original assignee (Brian) from the list of participants?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People automatically become participants when they interact with the PR (or you interact on their behalf, in this case), and I don't think they can be removed. However, Brian can unsubscribe from notifications in the PR's sidebar, and then his participation is purely historical.

Comment: I know that with Bitbucket, as least as a project admin, I was able to remove participants.  I wonder if Github project admins can do the same.  It's a useful feature where we can temporarily remove someone, do some cleanup, then put them back in to avoid spamming them with unnecessary notification emails.

Comment: A GitHub community forum feature request for this is here: https://github.community/t/how-to-remove-a-reviewer-from-a-pull-request/1415/4